# Managing multiple NSPersistentStores with PersistentStoreCoodinator

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, persistence

I am trying to get NSPersistentStoreCoordinator to manage the deletion and insertion of multiple persistent stores. So far I have managed to configure the PSC with two stores and I have been able to remove either store by specifying its index.

Like this…

```
NSPersistentStore *store = [[self.persistentStoreCoordinator persistentStores] objectAtIndex:0];

        if (![self.persistentStoreCoordinator removePersistentStore:store error:&error]) {

            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);

            abort();

        }

        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:store.URL error:&error];
```

But I'm finding that when I add the store back in to the PSC the index value is incorrect and it cannot be specified with the existing class methods. The consequence of this is that the new data is downloaded and added to the wrong store.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to this should be done?

**Background** (Updated)

The reason for using two persistent stores is so that I can designate a unique store for the two xml documents that will be downloaded over the network. As both these files are relatively large I am hoping to reduce network traffic. So a check is done to see if either file has been modified. If they have then the corresponding persistent store is deleted and a new store added. It's at this point the problem starts. Adding a new store always adds it to the end of the Persistent Stores Array. This appears to create a mismatch in the stores when merging the data back with the MOC.

**Code**
Here's what I've tried so far which removes and adds the persistent store but the new data is added to the wrong store.

```
static NSString * const kLastDateStoreUpdateKey = @"eventLastStoreUpdateKey";

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {

NSString *last_modified = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response allHeaderFields] objectForKey:@"Last-Modified"]];

NSDateFormatter *dFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"];
[dFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_GB"]];
[dFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];

dateModified = [dFormatter dateFromString:last_modified];
NSDate *previousDate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kLastDateStoreUpdateKey];

if (!previousDate || [previousDate compare:dateModified] != NSOrderedSame) {

    [self.managedObjectContext lock];
    [self.managedObjectContext reset];


    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:self.persistentStorePath]) {
        NSError *error = nil;

        NSArray *stores = [self.persistentStoreCoordinator persistentStores];
        NSURL *storeUrls = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:persistentStorePath];
        for (NSPersistentStore *store in stores){

            if ([[store.URL absoluteURL] isEqual:[storeUrls absoluteURL]]) {
                if (![self.persistentStoreCoordinator removePersistentStore:store error:&error]) {
                    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                    abort();
                }
                [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:store.URL error:&error];
                NSLog(@"Check store removed %@", [self.persistentStoreCoordinator persistentStores]);
            }
        }
    }

   NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:persistentStorePath];
    NSError *error = nil;
    [self.persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:nil error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"event error %@ %@",error, [[self.persistentStoreCoordinator persistentStores] objectAtIndex:0]);
    }
    NSLog(@"Check store added %@",self.persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores);

    [self.managedObjectContext unlock];

}else {
    [self cancelDownload];
    NSLog(@"event cancel %@ %@ %@",previousDate, dateModified, [self.persistentStoreCoordinator persistentStores]);
}
}
```

**Solved**
As Hunter pointed out below my PSC Configuration was set to as nil. So data was not being added to each individual Persistent Store. When I created a Configuration in the Core Data Model and targeted the relevant Entities I set the PSC to have that configuration. It then worked as expected. See below.

```
   NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:persistentStorePath];
NSError *error = nil;
[self.persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:@"ConfigEvent" URL:storeUrl options:nil error:&error];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"event error %@ %@",error, [[self.persistentStoreCoordinator persistentStores] objectAtIndex:0]);
}
NSLog(@"Check store added %@",self.persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores);
```

Comment: I'm not entirely clear why you think you need two stores? Can you elaborate? I may be able to suggest something simpler... As for the above, you can't count on the various positions in the array unless you explicitly manage for that. If you're set on your two stores, you might want to explicitly reference them with an ivar or property.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the failure you are seeing, it sounds like you're having trouble reading objects from you MOC after adding the new store. What does that have to do with the index of the persistent store in the persistent stores array?

Comment: One note - you probably don't want to do if (error) - NSError can often contain garbage values - you're better off logging the error if addPersistentStoreWithType returns nil, which signifies an error condition.

Comment: Ok - what I see here is you removing a store and adding a new fresh one but what I don't see is where you're saving your MOC and you're specifying the persistent store. In your code, how are you telling Core Data which store to store which data? Are you using Configurations for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you truly require the two stores [I can't tell from your explanation if that's really the best way to do this], you might want to reference them via properties or an ivar instead of relying on the array.

Alternatively, you could iterate through the PSC's stores array and identify each one by inspecting the URL.

**Update:**

If you're having trouble storing specific data in different NSPersistentStores, take a look at Core Data configurations. This allows you to tell Core Data to put specific entities in specific persistent stores.

You specify configurations in your model and when you add persistent stores. More here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdMOM.html

Comment: I think my question might need updating to cover what I've tried. In order to delete the correct Persistent Store I iterate through the array and compare the URL to make sure that I'm deleting the right one. Logs confirm this. My problem seems to happen when adding a new store back into the PSC. By default it is always added to the end of the Persistent Store array. So when I merge the new data back with MOC it has the wrong index and subsequently adds the data to the wrong store. Perhaps I should try adding another MOC?

Comment: It looks like your right. I don't have my Core Data Configurations set correctly to target each persistent store. I was assuming the newly added Data was correctly being added to each of the stores but whne I checked it was empty. Thank you very much!

Comment: Update: With Configurations now correctly set it all works as expected. The only problem that I encountered was "Default" is not a valid configuration name. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this with one Persistent Store Coordinator and two Managed Object Contexts.  You only need to go to the complexity of two Persistent Store Coordinators if you are experiencing locking which is hurting performance.

Remember: The Simplest Possible Thing (tm)

Comment: ?? I'm only using one Persistent Store Coordinator which is associated with one ManagedObjectContext. Maybe I'm being too simple.